# Finding Coefficient given 2 Equations of Lines and an Angle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algebraic-geometry

A line has equation
$$3x - ky = 0$$

Find the value of k if this line makes an angle of 45 degrees with the line

$$2x + 5y - 17 = 0$$

The answer among the choices is supposed to be $7$. But I keep on getting $$\frac{-9}{7}$$

I know that the angle formed between two intersecting lines is

$$\tan(\theta) = \frac{m_2 - m_1}{1+ m_2m_1}$$

here is my latest attempt:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Find the value of k if this line makes an angle of 45 degrees with the line $2x+5y-17=0$.

This means that you need to measure the counter-clockwise angle from $3x-ky=0$ to $2x+5y-17=0$. (You seem to measure the angle from $2x+5y-17=0$ to $3x-ky=0$.)

Hence, we need to have
$$\tan(45^\circ)=\frac{m_\color{red}{1}-m_\color{red}{2}}{1+m_1m_2}.$$
Solving this will give you $k=7$.

Answer (score 0):

$ 45^0$ is *between* the two given straight lines.

$$ \dfrac{3/k + 2/5}{1+ 3/k \cdot -2/5}=1 $$
$$ 15 + 2 k = 5 k - 6 $$
$$ k =7 $$